# Custom order Status on Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status, db-schema

I have built a Payment Module and I want to add some custom status on table sales_order_status using etc/db_schema.xml.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Made this, hope it will answer your question.

I did that threw an install data file though

```
/**
 * @param $statusLabel
 * @param $statusCode
 * @param $statusState
 */
private function addOrderStatus($statusLabel,$statusCode,$statusState){

    $statusRepository = $this->statusRepository->create();
    /** @var Status $status */
    $this->logger->logInfo("Create Status %s",[$statusCode]);
    $status = $this->statusFactory->create();
    $status->setData([
        'status' => $statusCode,
        'label' => $statusLabel,
    ]);
    try {
        $statusRepository->save($status);
        $this->logger->logSuccess("Status %s saved",[$statusCode]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->logError("Status %s already exist : %s",[$statusCode,$e->getMessage()]);
    }
    $this->logger->logInfo("Associate State %s to status",[$statusState,$statusCode]);
    try {
        $status->assignState($statusState, false, true);
        $this->logger->logSuccess("State %s associated",[$statusState]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->logError("State %s not associated : %s",[$statusState,$e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```